# run locally built website on my PC to another PC

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, wampserver

I built a website on local server not online which is wampServer and using codeigniter , 
I want run it on another PC how to move to this pc, do i need to build the database again and just move codeigniter ci folder that contaion my codes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to run it on both PC's or just the new one

Comment: no I want to run it just on another PC

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try your websites functionality from another PC. You can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com).

The documentation is clear and the setup takes less than a minute.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install WAMPServer on the new PC.
2. Copy the app folders to the new Wampserver.
3. Backup the database on the old WAMPServer
4. Restore the database on the new WAMPServer
5. When you are sure its working on the new WAMPServer Uninstall the old WAMPServer